# Importing data from csv2 comma isn't equal to RStudio comma

Tags: r, csv

I have an Excel file which I import in R thanks to

```
read.csv2('~/My/File/place.csv',sep=";")
```

Some of the cells have commas and when I try to compare them to specific value in R studio I have some pretty weird behaviour like :

```
> "‚"==","
[1] FALSE
```

or

```
> "‚"%in%","
[1] FALSE
```

By copy/pasting the previous example you could normaly see the same thing happening.

Of course when I try this kind of tests with data which aren't imported I don't get any issue.

Does anyone know why this kind of things is happening and if there is a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

The left hand expression that looks like a comma is actually a [single low-9 quotation mark in Unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/index.htm). Copy & pasting from what you have above, we can check the raw bits:

```
xx <- c(LHS = "‚", RHS = ",")

charToRaw(xx[1])
#[1] e2 80 9a

charToRaw(xx[2])
#[1] 2c

charToRaw(",")  ## typed in manually
#[1] 2c
```

Recreating these from Unicode,

```
(yy <- c(LHS = "\U201A", RHS = "\U002C"))
#LHS RHS 
#"‚" ","  

xx[1] == yy[1]
# LHS 
#TRUE 

xx[2] == yy[2]
# RHS 
#TRUE
```

---

As for fixing this, I'm not sure there is an easy solution because your computer does not understand that these symbols look alike, nor that you would like them to both be treated as commas. I would advise scanning your data for non-ASCII characters, though, as a starting point. This function is taken from the `?raw` help file:

```
isASCII <-  function(txt) all(charToRaw(txt) <= as.raw(127))
sapply(xx, isASCII)
#  LHS   RHS 
#FALSE  TRUE
```